# SQL can not refer table in from clause within where

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple SQL query used in oracle 11g

```
select something 
from sc 
where sc.column satisfies something
```

but I can not refer SC in the where composite, any one can help explain this, thanks in advance.

---second edit: I tested the sql command in oracle 19c it works but in 11g it does not work.

table contents

```
create table sc(
sno varchar2(10),
cno varchar2(10),
score number(4,2),
constraint pk_sc primary key (sno,cno)
);
```

example data

```
insert into sc values ('s001','c001',78.9);
insert into sc values ('s002','c001',80.9);
insert into sc values ('s003','c001',81.9);
insert into sc values ('s004','c001',60.9);
insert into sc values ('s001','c002',82.9);
insert into sc values ('s002','c002',72.9);
insert into sc values ('s003','c002',81.9);
insert into sc values ('s001','c003','59');
```

sql command

```
SELECT SNO
FROM SC A
WHERE 0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM 
               (SELECT B.CNO 
                FROM SC B
                WHERE B.SNO = 's001'
                MINUS
                SELECT C.CNO 
                FROM SC C
                WHERE A.SNO = C.SNO) --this is the error location, oracle reports invalid identifier A.
          );
```

Comment: What's your rdbms?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: A is defined outside of your subselect an id not accessible from there

Comment: I ran this with a dummy SC table and it worked.  Please show the complete error message, and the table definition.

Comment: @D-Shih database is oracle 11g

Comment: @W_O_L_F maybe you are right, but in the oracle 19c it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try a exists clause instead of where 0 =

```
SELECT SNO
FROM SC A
WHERE not exists (SELECT B.CNO 
                FROM SC B
                WHERE B.SNO = 's001'
                MINUS
                SELECT C.CNO 
                FROM SC C
                WHERE A.SNO = C.SNO) --this is the error location, oracle reports undefined A.
```

I'm assuming you want to return where there is not a match?

Comment: this code can not run on oracle 11g, but the latest version 19c is ok. I want to know why.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the CNO that are not only in SNO 's001'.

Then maybe this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SNO, cno
FROM SC sc
WHERE SNO = 's001'
  AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM SC sc2
        WHERE sc2.CNO = sc.CNO
          AND sc2.SNO != sc.SNO
      )
```